# What happens if I want to change an my instance type from one with EBS only to one that has Drive Attached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On AWS I have a running t2.small - this only comes with EBS storage. It currently has an 8 Gig EBS attached storage and I want to upgrade to an m1.small which has built in storage.

If I just switch to the m1.small what will it do? Will the EBS storage stay attached and not use the built in storage? Or will it duplicate my EBS storage? Or worse still will it not re-attach the EBS storage and I'll have to attach it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are currently running a T2.small, you will not be able to select an M1.small. Different virtualization types (HVM vs Paravirtualization).

When you change the instance type, you will be limited to instance types that match the virtualization type and storage type that you already have selected for your EC2 instance. The AMI that you selected will also limit which instance types that are supported.

Now, given that an instance type is available, your storage will stay the same and just your instance type will be changed.

Note: If the root device for your instance is an instance store volume, you must migrate your application to a new instance with the instance type that you need.

Comment: Possible point of clarification, if you launch an EBS-backed instance without ephemeral disks and later change the type to an instance with ephemeral disks, that *is* allowed, but you won't get the ephemeral disks.  NVMe SSDs might be an exception to this since they are always attached, iirc.

Comment: Michael - Good Points. I stay away from ephemeral disks in my designs. Customer just don't understand data disappearing on instance stop and start until a mistake happens.

Comment: Thank you for your responses... I noticed you can't upgrade to M1 (wonder if you can even create those still). I ended up going to an m3.medium. AWS just attached the existing EBS volume to the new instance. I assume the bundled storage is also attached